# Batch-run ALL migrations at once, syncdb style

Tags: python, django, database-migration

Our Django app contains hundreds of migrations (not South) and setting up a new instance now requires up to 20 minutes of migrating the empty DB.

Is there an option to force-sync the schema (the old syncdb way) and then fake the migration status for the new DB instance?

Comment: You probably want to look into [squashing your migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations).

Comment: This is unfortunately not an option as this is an app-in-a-box, and there are quite old instances which will habe to be eventually migrated

Comment: The squashed and unsquashed migrations can coexist until all systems are upgraded.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realized that before. @DanielRoseman please post it as an answer.